# mysql fulltext boolean NOT operator

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, not-operator

I'm doing a MySQL FULLTEXT search in boolean mode. According to the manual :

```
Note: The - operator acts only to exclude rows that are otherwise 
matched by  other search terms. Thus, a boolean-mode search that 
contains only terms preceded by - returns an empty result. It 
does not return “all rows except those containing any of the 
excluded terms.”
```

That's true.

So I use the NOT MATCH operator like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE MATCH (Column) AGAINST 
('bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND NOT MATCH (Column) AGAINST 
('barbar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

My question is: what is the effect of the + operator in the NOT MATCH field: is

```
AND NOT MATCH (Column) AGAINST ('foo bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

the same as :

```
AND NOT MATCH (Column) AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`+` operator signifies that the search literal is present. Per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> MySQL can perform boolean full-text searches using the IN BOOLEAN MODE
>   modifier. With this modifier, certain characters have special meaning
>   at the beginning or end of words in the search string. In the
>   following query, the **+** and **-** operators indicate that a word is
>   required to be **present or absent**, respectively,

For example, below query will retrieves all the rows that contain the word `MySQL` but that do not contain the word `YourSQL`

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

> +
>   A leading plus sign indicates that this word must be present in each
>   row that is returned.

**EDIT:**

`WHERE NOT MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` should mean get me all the rows where values of column isn't `foo` and `bar`. it should be a `negation` of `WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Yes, both are not same.

```
WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Says that get all rows where values of column are foo and bar

```
WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('foo bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Says that get all rows where values of column are foo or bar

Check the documentation carefully. It says

> [no operator] implies OR
>
> [+] implies AND

Comment: Thanks, I read that. But I don't understand what it means in the case of a NOT MATCH request. In a request WHERE NOT MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+foo +bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE) : does that mean that neither foo nor bar may be in column entries ? If it does that, than it should be the same as WHERE NOT MATCH (column) AGAINST ('foo bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE). But it isn't the same.