# Very advanced mysql search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am looking for some suggestions and hope I could find those here.

I have more fields of search, for an advanced search. Those are:

1. search CV that contains words...
2. search CV that NOT contains words,
3. within location or
4. out of a specific location
5. a specific education (to be included)

I will consider we have 3 groups:

1. which searches in CV,
2. for Location and
3. is education

I have the code above.
The problem is: it works if I search one group, but doesn't works combined. 
For example, if I search CV including word "a" and exclude location "uk" it shows nothing.

```
(SELECT account_id FROM work <br>
    WHERE <br>
    (company LIKE '%".$includewords."%'<br>
    OR function LIKE '%".$includewords."%' <br>
    OR duties LIKE '%".$includewords."%' <br>
    OR achievements LIKE '%".$includewords."%' <br>
    OR reason_for_leaving LIKE '%".$includewords."%')<br>
    AND <br>
    (company NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%'<br>
    OR function NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%' <br>
    OR duties NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%' <br>
    OR achievements NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%' <br>
    OR reason_for_leaving NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%'))<br><br>
    UNION<br><br>
    (SELECT account_id FROM personal <br>
    WHERE <br>
    actual_city LIKE '%".$includelocation."%'<br>
    AND<br>
    actual_city NOT LIKE '%".$excludelocation."%'<br>
    )<br><br>
    UNION<br><br>
    (SELECT account_id FROM education <br>
    WHERE <br>
    institution LIKE '%".$school."%' OR<br>
    grade_achieved LIKE '%".$school."%'<br>
    )
```

As result, if I search combined, it returns no error and 0 results, as no results were found.

Comment: Is doing fulltext index and fulltext search with `match against` an option? If yes, see if this can get you started in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696291/mysql-fulltext-boolean-not-operator

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. It might help to post concrete values for your variables (including a working 1-group and non-working-2-group search) and actual and expected result. What you currently describe seems inaccurate, since `union` can only extend a resultset - unless you changed something else or your (1-group) search was not accurate (as e.g. `like '%%'` for empty variables is always true/`NOT LIKE '%".$excludewords."%'`for an empty `$excludewords` is always false), so the results you got might have come from another "group") (or you get an error).

Comment: Also, your first `excludewords`-part seems incorrect: even though `company` might be `apple`, since `function` is (probably) `not like '%apple%'`, the final `or`-ed expression stays true.